# Regex to ignore matches that have a specific string in front of it

Tags: php, regex

I have this string stored in php:

```
Keyboard layout codes found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx test 123

test https://google.com

test google.com

<img src='http://example.com/pages/projects/uploader/files/2017-06-16%2011_27_36-Settings.png'>Link Converted to Image</img>
```

The `img` element was made with a prevous regex;

```
$url = '~(https|http)?(://)((\S)+(png|jpg|gif|jpeg))~';
$output = preg_replace($url, "<img src='$0'>Link Converted to Image</img>", $output);
```

My problem is, now I want to convert the regular links to an `a` element.

I have this regex, which works except for one problem.

```
$url = '~(https|http)?(://)?((\S)+[.]+(\w*))~';
$output = preg_replace($url, "<img src='$0'>Link Converted to Image</img>", $output);
```

This regex ALSO converts the link that has already become an `img` element, so it puts an `a` element in the source of the `img` element. My thinking on avoiding this problem is to ignore a preg match checking if the match starts with `src='`, but I can't figure out how to actually do this.

Am I doing this incorrectly? What is the most common/effecient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @Jan's answer, although there may be some drawbacks with this workaround, it will match URL-like strings:

```
<img.+?</img>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?:https?\S+|(?:(?!:)(?(1)\S|(\w)))*\.\w{2,5})
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/0mBxI6/1)

Breakdown:

```
(?:             # Open a NCG (a)
    (?!:)       # Next immediate character shouldn't be a colon `:`
    (?(1)\S     # If CG #1 exists match a non-whitespace character
    |           # otherwise
    (\w))       # Match a word character (a URL begins with a word character)
)*              # As much as possbile (this cluster denotes a tempered pattern)
\.\w{2,5}       # Match TLD
```

Drawbacks:

1. TLD's character limit
2. Partial match of URLs containing a port number

Comment: That's awesome, how does it work? Looking at it I can't pick it apart, as a newbie with regex. Also, what would the drawbacks be?

Comment: Please check update. Drawbacks would be TLD's which are limited up to 5 characters or excluding URLs with port number as we are explicitly omitting `:` from URL except the one right after `http`. However you can work on it to make it complete.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the breakdown. Regex is confusing! I don't think any of those drawbacks are going to matter in my situation, so thank you! I wish I could accept 2 answers as correct.

Comment: There is still a minor issue with URL's that don't have the http|https prefix though. For example, if the link was visible on this page `http://example.com/pages/projects/` and it converted `google.com` to a link, the `a` element would actually go to `http://example.com/pages/projects/google.com`. Is there a way to solve this via substitution?

Comment: Then instead you should use `preg_replace_callback` and check if current match contains capturing group #1. [Check it here](https://3v4l.org/f0Vgg). @GrumpyCrouton

Answer (score 2):

A good example for `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
<img.+?</img>(*SKIP)(*FAIL) # match <img> tags and throw them away
|                           # or
\bhttps?\S+\b               # a link starting with http/https
```

---

In `PHP`:

```
<?php

$string = <<<DATA
Keyboard layout codes found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx test 123

test https://google.com

<img src='http://example.com/pages/projects/uploader/files/2017-06-16%2011_27_36-Settings.png'>Link Converted to Image</img>
DATA;

$regex = '~<img.+?</img>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\bhttps?\S+\b~';

$string = preg_replace($regex, "<a href='$0'>$0</a>", $string);
echo $string;
?>
```

Comment: Make it lazy `<img.+?</img>`.

Comment: This doesn't match a string that is, for example, just `google.com`, is there a way to give it this functionality?

Comment: @revo: Right you are. Need some sleep obviously.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: That's true but you'll need to elaborate on the types of your expected links then.

Comment: If *google.com* is considered an URL then *foo.bar* should be too. Not right. @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: I was able to combine your answer with my already working regex, giving me `<img.+?</img>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(https|http)?(://)?((\S)+[.]+(\w*))` which seems to work using https://regex101.com/r/luIPVx/1/

Comment: @revo: I've always thought that `foo.bar` gets you to the Silicon Valley immediately :)

Comment: You're right about the `foo.bar` example. What about adding common url endings like `com|net|org` etc, like I did with the images? Is there a downside to this besides maintenence?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: No, but you'll need to update your code when there are new endings (and they're popping up every time, consider `.shop`).

Comment: @Jan This code is mostly used in a project management software I am working on for internal use. Most URL's that are posted are going to be pretty common TLD

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: Then you might very well get along with this solution.

Comment: @Jan Well I have discovered another problem. When changing links that do not start with `http://` or `https://` the link does not actually work, as the link is viewed as a directory of the current site, so I'm just going to use your solution fully :)